# CentOS 6.4 / Samba4 standalone server using OpenLDAP backend

Tags: centos, openldap, samba

I have a `OpenLDAP` server (v2.4) running on `CentOS` 6.4. It works great! I'm using this OpenLdap server as authenticate backend for several service like `Gitlab`, `Redmine`, etc.

Now I want to setup another `Samba` standalone server and use the OpenLDAP server as auth backend for existed users in OpenLDAP. I tried with `samba` v3.6.9 but after configure auth backend as `ldapsam`  in `smb.conf` I can't login using LDAP account.

When I run

```
smbclient -L localhost -U%
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    allusers        Disk      All Users
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server Version 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    VAGRANT-CENTOS64     Samba Server Version 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            MY_MACHINE
```

But when I login with my test acc

```
smbclient -L localhost -U test
Enter test's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

Here is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` (print out from `testparm`)

```
[global]
        workgroup = MYGROUP
        server string = Samba Server Version %v
        passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://192.168.1.201/
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        ldap admin dn = cn=Manager,dc=mycompany,dc=com
        ldap passwd sync = yes
        ldap suffix = dc=mycompany,dc=com
        ldap ssl = no
        ldap debug level = 1
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        cups options = raw
```

In the Samba server. I use `sssd` to authenticate with OpenLDAP. From this Samba machine I can query user by `ldapsearch` command. I can get the user info by `id LDAP_USER` and `ssh` to this machine by any LDAP_USER/password. Here is my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

```
[domain/mycompany.com]

ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
cache_credentials = True
ldap_search_base = dc=mycompany,dc=com
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://192.168.1.201:636
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/certs
ldap_tls_reqcert = never

[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2

domains = mycompany.com
```

On OpenLDAP server, I use LDAP Account Manager to manage user/group. I import `samba` schema and check everything ok in LAM. I also enable `samba3` extension for some users in LDAP to test. I also open ports 137, 138, 139, 445 (tcp) in Samba server.

So what should I do next?
I just want to reuse the user from OpenLDAP server. I don't want to create any user from samba. Please give me suggestions about this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure samba knows the password of the admin DN to bind to LDAP server. This is done with

`smbpasswd -w <secret>`

before starting Samba.

Now, if that is done, do you have NTLM passwords created for your users? Samba checks sambaNTPassword and sambaLMPassword attributes when performing authentication for the user. For changing these attributes at the time user changes own password through LDAP, you need to use `smbk5pwd` OpenLDAP overlay and set `ldap passwd sync = only` in `smb.conf` instead of `ldap passwd sync = yes` as you did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved the problem. In any case if you install a samba 4 standalone server using a ldap remote server you have to establish the same SID that domain server (it's not necessary to join it to the domain). Obviously, the command `net setlocalid <sid domain>` won't work on a local machine. You have to modify the value in the LDAP tree, searching the name of the netbios machine... I recommend you use a LDAP browser for this purpose...

Good Luck